# JdbcTemplate batch update in postgresql - date loses time?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I am inserting a list of object with `java.util.date` in format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD` (`2008-09-26T14:34:59+02:00`).

SQL:

> INSERT INTO cdate
>   (key,valuedate,user_id) VALUES(?,?,?)

```
BatchPreparedStatementSetter bpss = new MetaJdbc().setMetaBatchPreparedStatement(
                    list, userId);
getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql,bpss);
```

Date **is** in right format, but in PostgreSQL it saves only just like that: "`2008-09-26 00:00:00+02`"

Edit:
I was in a hurry before... I did not give enough info, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use java.sql.Timestamp instead. And by the way, your posted snippets barely giving us any hint.

Comment: I added edit. But even so, you got it :) I totally forgot and use java.sql.Date

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the field in the database? Is it date or datetime?

Also, what is this MetaJdbc class? It may put the wrong type ([DATE](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#DATE) instead of [TIMESTAMP](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#TIMESTAMP))